# How to change button background with an image from an array (android)?

Tags: android, button, background

I know how to change a button background image:

> cevap1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);

However, I actually want to set the button background to an image from an array. How can I do that?

> cevap1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.array[1]);

this does not work of course. :))

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 4):

just try this

```
  int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};
  yourbutton.setBackgroundResource(myImageList[1]);
```

all resources files are identified by int value on android, so you need create int array.

Answer (score 1):

try like that

```
Integer[] image = {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4,
            R.drawable.pic5,
            R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7                    
    };
```

and call

```
cevap1.setBackgroundResource(image[0]);
```